# How can I group the individual sum of six measures by color using the Treemap

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to group the sum of each measure (Crm, MIM, Online, Email, Phones and Mail) to have its own color in a Treemap. I want it to be how I currently have Program grouped.
[image: Tableau]

Answer (score 1):

Per [Tableau Help](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_treemap.html), the structure of treemaps are determined by dimensions - not measures. You can sum your measures in a calculated measure field, then convert that calculation to a discrete dimension. Maybe if you chose to bin your resulting values into categorical ranges the results would be meaningful.